# vlc shows black screen on zero 2w running Bullseye

Tags: ssh, vlc

If I use the vlc GUI or call a python script from the local command line:

```
    import vlc

    media = vlc.MediaPlayer("myfile.mp4")
    media.play()
```

I get a black screen instead of a video.

HOWEVER, if I SSH into the Pi and run the same command line script from there ... I see the video fullscreen on the Pi HDMI display.

This tells me vlc on the Zero 2W is possible, with the correct command/setup. Is there anyone with an idea of how to approach this issue?

I am running Bullseye and vlc media player 3.0.18 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2).